# Telegram: как методом sendMessage отдать ожидание и отправить сообщение, когда будет готово?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, telegram, бот, sendmessage

Узнал, что можно отправлять sendMessage Telegram API ожидание API telegram, сохранить id сообщения пользователя, а потом, когда сообщение сформируется в боте, отправить его..

Читаю документацию бот апи Telegram:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options

Хоть убей не понимаю, как это реализовать:

$urlQuery = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=". $chatId ."&text=" . $textMessage . "&drop_pending_updates=true";

$result = file_get_contents($urlQuery);

Подскажите, пожалуйста, опытные специалисты как это делается, нигде не нашел подробностей (

Comment: флаг `drop_pending_updates` используется в подписке и отписке от хук. При чем тут `sendMessage`?

Comment: @teran я с помощью drop_pending_updates пытался убить задваивающиеся сообщения от бота.. он висит долго, а потом присылает правильный ответ на сообщение пользователя, но много кратно его дублирует. В любом случае, что до его добавления сообщения дублировались, что после, ничего не поменялось

Comment: @teran то есть не в этом моя проблема, я хотел сказать